# How to achieve key/value pair max accurately with simple string using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a simple string value line that contains the below content.

```
logo Name raj mobile 9038874774 address 6-98 india bill auto generated
```

Now I am trying key/Value pair to achieve my detail and the pair value output expecting like below

```
[0] Key: Name  value:Raj
[1] Key: Mobile value:9038874774
[2] Key: Address value:6-98 india
```

Below is code trying to achieve requirement

```
string[] lines = new string[] { "logo Name raj mobile 9038874774 address 6-98 india bill auto generated" };
   
// Get the position of the empty sign within each line

var pairs = lines.Select(l => new { Line = l, Pos = l.IndexOf(" ") });

// Build a dictionary of key/value pairs by splitting the string at the empty sign
var dictionary = pairs.ToDictionary(p => p.Line.Substring(0, p.Pos), p => p.Line.Substring(p.Pos + 1));

// Now you can retrieve values by key:
var value1 = dictionary["Name"];
```

Below is output looks like in the debugger

[image]

The text string contains some non-required words like logo and bill auto generated no need for these words to be required into key/value pairs. Please suggest how to achieve this max accurately and the data of string getting from the image file converted into a text string using terrasact OCR

Comment: Are the list of possible keys known?  Perhaps use `string.Split` then iterate, and each time a key is found use that as the key, then the value for that key is until next key is found.

Comment: Yes Name,mobile and address are my keys and Please can you provide answer into code will much help to me. @AndrewS

Comment: If `Name`, `mobile`, and `address` are the keys, then the expected address should be *"6-98 india bill auto generated"?* If not, then what's the specification?

Comment: Address should be "6-98 india" only this much only meaning  some data are there in the string that is not require and we can delete from string also. my agenda requirement is like this: https://nanonets.com/blog/how-to-ocr-purchase-orders-for-automation/#3-way-matching . @MarkSeemann

Comment: If you provide your answer will be good help for me. @MarkSeemann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using [string.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0).  I changed `line` to match the case of the keys, so you might have to deal with case issues.  Also, I'm assuming *Bill* is a key that is safe to be ignored (same concern that @Mark Seemann raised in the comments.)

There are other potential key issues though, for example, what if the name value is *Bill*?

```
private static readonly HashSet<string> _extractKeys = new() { "Name", "Mobile", "Address" };
private static readonly HashSet<string> _ignoredKeys = new() { "Bill" };

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var line = "logo Name raj Mobile 9038874774 Address 6-98 india Bill auto generated";
    var splitLine = line.Split(' ');

    var pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    for (var i = 0; i < splitLine.Length; i++)
    {
        var candidateKey = splitLine[i];
        if (!_extractKeys.Contains(candidateKey))
        {
            continue;
        }

        var value = "";
        for (var v = i + 1; v < splitLine.Length; v++)
        {
            var candidateValuePart = splitLine[v];
            if (_ignoredKeys.Contains(candidateValuePart) || _extractKeys.Contains(candidateValuePart))
            {
                i = v - 1;
                break;
            }

            value = value + candidateValuePart + " ";
        }

        pairs.Add(candidateKey, value.Trim());
    }

    foreach (var kv in pairs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", kv.Key, kv.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your code is working fine nice effort and logic you are great. @Andrew S

Comment: Can you add comments each line of on your code to better understanding of your code. @Andrew S

Comment: Can you suggest more sample data. what happens if the name is "John W. Smith". I also need more address samples is not fix na. How to manage these things. @Andrew S

Answer (score 1):

This really [looks like a parsing problem](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2023/08/28/a-first-crack-at-the-args-kata), but a quick-and-dirty implementation might be something like this:

```
private static IDictionary<string, string> Parse(string input)
{
    var keys = ImmutableHashSet.Create(
        StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase, "Name", "Mobile", "Address");
    var ignoredKeys = ImmutableHashSet.Create(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase, "Bill");
    var allKeys = keys.Union(ignoredKeys);
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    string? currentKey = null;
    foreach (var word in input.Split(' '))
    {
        if (allKeys.TryGetValue(word, out var key))
        {
            if (key != null)
                dict[key] = "";
            currentKey = key;
        }
        else if (currentKey != null && dict.TryGetValue(currentKey, out var s))
            dict[currentKey] = (s + " " + word).Trim();
    }

    return new Dictionary<string, string>(dict.ExceptBy(ignoredKeys, kvp => kvp.Key));
}
```

Here, I'm assuming that `"bill"` is also a sort of key that should just be ignored.

Comment: Can you suggest more sample data. what happens if the name is "John W. Smith". I also need more address samples is not fix na. How to manage these things. @Mark Seemann